# SceneManager does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Got a problem with using the scene manager. Already had a **using UnityEngine.SceneManagement** still shows the error of both LoadScene and GetActiveScene. I don't have a class such as "SceneManager". Here is the code.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool alive = true;

    public float speed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    float horizontalInput;
    float horizontalMultiplier = 1.7f; 

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (!alive) return;


        Vector3 forwardMove = transform.forward * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        Vector3 horizontalMove = transform.right * horizontalInput * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime * horizontalMultiplier;
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + forwardMove + horizontalMove);
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        if (transform.position.y < -5)
        {
            end();
        }
    }

    public void end ()
    {
        alive = false;

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I have.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you have another SceneManager class in your project?

Comment: And following on what Ilya says, what happens if instead you write `UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name)`? (Though as far as I understand, Unity would have alerted a name resolve collision if truly there were 2 of the same name.)

Comment: I don't have a SceneManager class in my project as I double checked on my Assets folder. I wrote edited the code with your modification and it run successfully. I forgot about the "GameObject" as it reported a definition error, shoud have been with a lowercase 'g' or "gameObject"

Comment: What happens if you hover the `SceneManager` and press F12 (assuming your are using some decent IDE)?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022 IDE that comes with UnityHub. Actually it did nothing on the IDE (idk why my IDE does not even do anything when I hover). I am still trying to fix this in my IDE but, overall it is already fixed. I used @PhilippLenssen and did a little modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all try:

```
UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene( "myScene");
```

There can be 2 troubles:

First -

> This happened to me. I had downloaded an asset off the store called Falling Leaves. It included a script called SceneManager. Namespaces should be better utilized for store assets. I'll have to take a look at the code to my own to make sure I'm not breaking someone else's project unintentionally.

Second - if you are wirtting kinda your own lib for unity check that all .dll / projects was imported or if you are writting code in folder that marked with .asmdef this is tool in unity that helps with faster compile and more separeted development ([there](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)) and if you are do smth with this asmdef file and checkbox "include unity engine" is not setted as true this is too can be reason so check pls

Same question was answered there https://forum.unity.com/threads/scenemanager-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-loadscene.388892/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to be `using UnityEngine;` before actually `using UnityEngine.SceneManagement`
here's an example

`using UnityEngine; using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;`

the problem here is that your using a part or branch or something of EnityEngine before using UnityEngine itself